# What directory should the frontend user login template be put into?

Tags: authentication, wagtail, user-management

Since I want to keep the admin login separate from the user login on my Wagtail site, I'm trying to use the login page settings mentioned in this [section of the documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html#login-page) to direct people to a custom login page. I added the following settings to my base.py folder in the settings directory for my WT project under #Wagtail settings:

```
WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE = 'base/login.html'
```

My project is structured similar to the [bakerydemo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo), so there is a base app that manages a lot of the shared pieces of the site. I put my login.html in the templates directory for the base app. See link below for screenshot.

[Screenshot of project directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CtPQ.png)

I am getting a 404 error whenever I try to navigate to the login URL I specified. Is there a setting I missed? Did I put the template in the wrong directory? Still getting used to how WT structures projects, so any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only set one of `WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_URL` and `WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE`, not both.

`WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE` is used if you want to use Wagtail's own login view (located at the URL `/_util/login/`), but want to customise its template. If you're going down this route, a path like `'base/login.html'` is correct - Django will search within all template directories for a file matching this path.

`WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_URL` is used if you want to provide your own view code. To use this, you'll need to write the view function (most likely inheriting from [Django's LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)) and register it in the URL config, then point `WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_URL` at the resulting URL. In this case, your view function will be responsible for rendering an appropriate template, so `WAGTAIL_FRONTEND_LOGIN_TEMPLATE` will not come into play.

Comment: Thanks do much for the clarification! Everything makes a lot more sense now.